# Difficulty resolving "fatal error: charconv: No such file or directory"

Tags: compiling

I am having difficulty resolving the error below:

```shellsession
$ g++ -std=c++17 -fno-exceptions -Wno-deprecated-declarations -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I./../include -g -O2 -MT util.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/util.Tpo -c util.cc  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/util.o
util.cc:23:10: fatal error: charconv: No such file or directory
```

Information:

```shellsession
$ uname -a
Linux run-6594505b5bdd472c40e6af6d-tpnhw 5.10.192-183.736.amzn2.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Sep 6 21:15:41 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ gcc --version
gcc-10 (Ubuntu 10.3.0-1ubuntu1~18.04~1) 10.3.0
```

The only suggestions I've seen in the forums involve the gcc and g++ versions, but these seem recent enough.

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
> apt-get install apt-file 
> apt-file update

# Now search dependency
> apt-file search charconv
```

I think you need to install `libc++-[VERSION]-dev`

Comment: libc++-10-dev is installed:                                                                                     /usr/lib$ apt-cache policy libstdc++-10-dev
libstdc++-10-dev:
  Installed: 10.3.0-1ubuntu1~18.04~1
  Candidate: 10.3.0-1ubuntu1~18.04~1